# Parsing the results returned via DHCPd's OMAPI interface

Tags: dhcp-server

I'm experimenting with OMAPI as a means of giving our support staff additional insight into the state of a subscriber's service. Anyone who's ever played with OMAPI knows two things:

1. The documentation is awful
2. Assuming you get past the documentation's awfulness, the resulting objects contain hexadecimal representations of each value.

Now, I can convert IP addresses from the ab:ab:ab:ab format that they're returned in into dotted decimal without issue but does anyone know how to convert the other values into something sane, specifically, the start/end values.

Also, are the subnet values representative of the subnet mask assigned to the subscriber or are they related to something else? For example, I have a subscriber whose subnet mask is 255.255.224.0 but the subnet value returned by OMAPI is 00:00:00:09.

**Update:**

Okay, I've sussed out the starts/ends thing - basically, you remove the colons from the hexadecimal value, convert to int and then run it through, say, date() (PHP) or localtime() (Perl). E.g.,

*4e:4a:03:74* becomes *4e4a0374*, expressed as an int *1313473396* and then passed to date('Ymd G:i:s') to give us *20110816 6:43:16*

I'm still not sure what the subnet value is (I mean, I'm guessing it somehow relates to the subnet mask but I'm not sure how).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so in addition to figuring out the time stuff, I've also discovered (er... by reading the effin' manual, no less) that the 'subnet' and 'pool' keys refer to OMAPI objects for the subnet and pool declarations in dhcpd.conf. However, those objects can't currently be read.